# Can I insert only if two fields are not a match, but with a primary key that auto increments?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have 3 fields in a table:

id, client_id, username

The client_id and username combination should never be duplicates. The original thought was to use a composite primary key for client_id and username. This however did not allow my "ID" field to auto increment as it was not primary.

If I were to add my ID to my composite, there would never be a duplicate as the ID is always changing.

The latest I have is a basic:

```
"INSERT IGNORE INTO users (client_id, username) VALUES(cid,username)"
```

Is there a way to check that client_id and username are a match for any previous records, and if they are, then don't add them? The above does not work.

Comment: make both of them combined as a unique key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE ( client_id ,username);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a unique key by combination of client_id ,username in your table .

Answer (score 0):

You can create the table like this so that client_id and username will'nt get matched for any previous records...

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id int,
    client_id int,
    username varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY('id','client_id')

);
```